# Unable to see console output in assistant editor using swift playground

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

Can any one explain me , why console output is not visible in assistant editor. the bar on the right is only showing "Hello, playground" and the assistant editor is showing blank.

// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

```
   import UIKit

   var str = "Hello, playground"

   println("Hello")

   NSLog("Hello, world")
```

Comment: just quit and Re-launch Xcode .

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WS1Lp.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the cocoa library :

```
import Cocoa
```

This Sample working fine for me:

```
import Cocoa

var str = "Hello, playground"
println("Hello")

NSLog("Hello, world")
```

Comment: You might get this exception  `Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:5:8: error: no such module 'UIKit'
import UIKit` , If you use the `import UIKit`

Comment: It's because you use Platform: OS X in Playground Settings (it's default for now, but can be changed to iOS, and then you have to import UIKit).